# Why are different forms of Vishnu to be remembered while doing different types of work in the Vishnu Shodasanama Stotra?

Tags: vishnu, stotra

Please explain the reasons for the different forms of Vishnu needing to be remembered when doing different types of work in the Vishnu Shodashnaam Stotra.

For example: Why is the action of taking medicine related to Vishnu and not Ram? Also as Vishnu is himself in all the forms, how are we to understand different forms differently?

Another example: Is it the case that Govinda should be remembered when having a bad dream but not some other form?

> औषधे चिंतयेद् विष्णुं
>
> भोजने च जनार्दनं
>
> शयने पद्मनाभं च
>
> विवाहे च प्रजापतिं
>
> युद्धे चक्रधरं देवं
>
> प्रवासे च त्रिविक्रमं
>
> नारायणं तनुत्यागे
>
> श्रीधरं प्रियसंगमे
>
> दुःस्वप्ने स्मर गोविन्दं
>
> संकटे मधुसुदनं
>
> कानने नरसिंहं च
>
> पावके जलशायिनं
>
> जलमध्ये वराहं च
>
> पर्वते रघुनन्दनं
>
> गमने वामनं चैव
>
> सर्वकार्येषु माधवं
>
> षोडशैतानि नामानि
>
> प्रातर् उत्थाय यः पठेत्
>
> सर्वपापविनिर्मुक्तो
>
> विष्णुलोकं समाप्नुयात्

Comment: you could understand that yourself easily if you contemplate on the names,But writing these wiill be personal opinion and flagged and deleted as they are probably nnot mentioned in any scripture so far as I know.

Comment: maybe you can still tell a bit about it in the comments here

Comment: And 'sarvakaryeshu madhavam means that there is no strict restriction

Comment: For example, padmanava is the lying form, Rama lived on chitrakut hill, simha lives in forest etc etc

Comment: @commonman I didn't get it
How did you derive that? What does madhav word represent? Or what is the guna of the madhava form?

Comment: @commonman I get for many of them like sridharam, narasingham, chakradharam etc.. But don't get for a few others

Comment: madhava is the general name for His sweet nature, derived from madhu.

Comment: Not that exact I think, but could be explained

Comment: @commonman Scriptures are not the only sources we can cite here. We can explain the answer based on any source. We can also explain the meaning based on our expertise in language and subject. You can write the answer and not wait only for scriptural reference.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Thanks, I shall try:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this lies in understanding two aspects. But before that, let me remind that according to our bhakti-scriptures, Nama(Name of God) and Nami(God) are one and the same.And, chanting the holy names is prescribed at any time during day or night :

> nAmnAm akAri vahudhA nija-sarva-shaktis tatrArpirto niyamitah **smarane na kAlah** (Mahaprabhu Sri Chaitanya), meaning : O Lord! You have taken various names, put all your power in each and **there is no fixed time to chant them.**

Even then, such stotras are prescribed because, 1. people love variety and 2. In sanskrit, 'anuprasa' (Alliteration, or similar sounding words or letters are very often used and appeciated).

Now let us see some of the names and the mentioned activities:

1. AUSHAdha and vISHnu

2.bhoJAN and JANardana

3. gaMANa and vAMANa

For the rest,

4. PadmanAva is a lying form and so prescribed while lying,
5. Prajapati is related to procreation and so prescribed while marrying
6. Chakradhara is a warrior form holding sudarshana and so prescribed during war
7. Trivikrama or VAmana had spread His feet everywhere and so prescribed in foreign land
8. Narayana is the supreme goal of all men and so prescribed while leaving the body

9.Sridhara is Vishnu's name assocaiated with His dear consort and so prescribed while meeting the dear ones.

10. Govinda is a name that has various meanings, but all are pious and faer-removing and so prescribed while having horrible dreams.
11. Madhusudana killed Madhu and saved Brahmaa's life and so is prescribed while faced with danger.
12. Simha lives in forests and so Narasimha is prescribed while being in forest.
13. JalasAyi the form is lying on water and so prescribed while faced with fire ans water extinguishes fire.
14. Varaha saved the earth from the 'pralaya'- water holding it on tooth and so prescribed while on or in water.
15. Raghunandana (Rama) lived on Chitrakuta hill for some time and so this name is prescribed while remeining on hills.
16. MAdhava comes from Madhu which reminds the sweet nature of the Lord and so prescribed in all activities so that all experiences are made 'madhumaya' by His grace.

This completes the list.